# How to allow a Community user to generate a notification?

Tags: community, notification

With Communities, you get this internal user to external (community user) notification UI "for free" via a click on the bell icon:

[image: Notifications pane screen shot]

Before we start creating something ourselves for communication in the opposite direction, from external (community user) to internal user, if there some standard way of providing that feature in a Community?

Comment: If the community users can see internal users records , then they should be able to @mention an internal user in a Chatter post. This will trigger the notification bell in the internal app for the internal user. Is there other use case besides chatter that u need?

Comment: Thanks @Shamina. The generic requirement I'm looking to meet is 2 way communication, so the simpler the better i.e. just a place to enter a message, with who gets that message being open ended.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, if your business rules allow it, you can add the internal user profiles as members of the community, then the community user can simply communicate with an internal user via Chatter and @mention the name of an internal user in the post.

This will display the notification to the internal user within the internal SF application, as shown in the screenshot below where a community users sent chatter message to an internal user.

You might as well check [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312503&type=1&mode=1) in case community user have trouble @mention internal user.

[image]

Comment: So if I wanted to hide the mention part, I could create a small piece of UI and programmatically create the chatter post adding in the @mention part?

Comment: I have not tried it but seems that this should be feasible using [ConnectAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_mention.htm) for Chatter in apex